# Harvest for Trello plugin not showing in Fluid app

Tags: trello, harvest

I have enabled the "Harvest Time Tracking" plugin in Trello. However, I cannot see the plugin under "Actions" when I view Trello in a Fluid app. (For those who are not familiar, Fluid let's you create a standalone app from a website.)

I've tried to clear the cache in Fluid, both in the app itself as well as using CCleaner, but nothing I've tried allows the "Track Time" option to show up in the Fluid app (I can see this option just fine if I simply browse to trello.com, however).

Comment: "Harvest for Trello" is a Chrome extension.  I suspect that this will not run in Fluid.

Comment: You are correct Aaron, Harvest for Trello is a Chrome extension. I didn't even think of that aspect. I create standalone apps in Windows OS using Chrome, so I got a little confused. I do believe you are correct, it probably won't work because it's not Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Fluid is great, and is generally my preference when creating "standalone" apps on MacOS, however, if anyone else runs into this and wants to create a standalone app using chrome, I came across this article: http://www.lessannoyingcrm.com/articles/149/Create_application_shortcuts_in_Google_Chrome_on_a_Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) here.

You might try changing your FluidApp's User-Agent string to Safari:

> Main Menu → Fluid App Menu (to the left of File menu) → User Agent → Safari

Then reload the page (or "go home" with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks, Todd! I'd actually tried this as well, but still to no avail. It seems the answer above is the correct one, and that Chrome extensions will not run in FluidApp. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize this was a Chrome extension. That is correct, Chrome extensions will absolutely not work with FluidApps.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old as **** by know, but in case anyone stumbles upon it I thought I'd chip in with a little tip:

If you are running OSX, there's a nifty little project on Github called [Epichrome](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome) which allow you to create webapps framed in a native browser-window, much in the same way as Fluid.app is doing – the difference being that for Epichrome-based apps, the underlying engine is Chrome/Blink, and not Safari/Webkit. This in turn enable you to use the same Chrome plugins that you use and love in your Chrome browser, inside your generated site-specific-browser-app. Here's the two first paragraphs from the readme:

> Epichrome is made up of two parts: an AppleScript-based Mac application (Epichrome.app) and a companion Chrome extension (Epichrome Helper). Epichrome.app creates Chrome-based site-specific browsers (SSBs) for Mac OSX (Chrome must be installed in order to run them, but they are full Mac apps, each with its own separate Chrome profile).
>
> Each app automatically installs Epichrome Helper, which uses rules to decide which links the app should handle itself, and which should be sent to the default web browser.

I was an avid Fluid.app user before, but have switched to Epichrome since it gives me the same benefits without having to give up the Chrome plugins that I use together with the sites (Trello, for example).

Easiest way to get started is to download one of the release binaries – here's a link to the release notes of 2.1.11 which was released on 22 feb 2016:
[Epichrome 2.1.11 release notes](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome/releases/tag/v2.1.11)

(for the record, I am in no way affiliated with the Epichrome project, I just wanted to present one possible solution to this question).